# How can I do total count of values accordingly selected feild in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array of objects, for exemple:

```
let arr = [
  {title:apple,quantity:2},
  {title:banana,quantity:3},
  {title:apple,quantity:5},
  {title:banana,quantity:7}
];
```

array containe many same objects, and i want recived array with uniqe object :

```
let result  = [
  {title:apple,quantity:7},
  {title:banana,quantity:10}
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Wont this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over your array and filter out all the object with same title. Then use reduce to add all the quantity and return a new object. Code is below,

```
let newArr = [];

arr.forEach((currentObj) => {
    const alreadyExists = newArr.findIndex(item => currentObj.title === item.title) > -1;
    if(!alreadyExists) {    
        const filtered = arr.filter(item => item.title === currentObj.title);
        const newObject = filtered.reduce((acc, curr) => { return {...acc, quantity: acc.quantity += curr.quantity}}, {...currentObj, quantity: 0})
        newArr.push(newObject);
    }
})
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is done on a phone so may have some typos but the gist is there:

```js
const resultObj = arr.reduce((acc,curr) =>{
acc[curr.title] = acc[curr.title]== undefined? curr.quantity: acc[curr.title] + curr.quantity
return acc
},{})

const resultArr = Object.entries(resultObj).map([key,value]=>({title:key,quantity:value}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in "one line" using [arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) but it won't be very readable unless you know what's happening inside:

```js
let arr = [
  {title: "apple",quantity:2},
  {title: "banana",quantity:3},
  {title: "apple",quantity:5},
  {title: "banana",quantity:7}
];

let newArr = [...arr.reduce((acc, {title, quantity}) => 
   (acc.set(title, quantity + acc.get(title) || 0), acc), new Map())
].map(([title, quantity]) => ({title, quantity}));

console.log(newArr);
```

So basically the first part is the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method:

```js
arr.reduce((acc, {title, quantity}) => 
   (acc.set(title, quantity + acc.get(title) || 0), acc), new Map())
```

That will returns a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object, where each title is a `key` (e.g. "apple") and the quantity is the value of the key.

At this point you have to convert the `Map` object into an array again, and you do it using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

After you got an array back, you will have it in the following form:

```js
[["apple", 7], ["banana", 10]]
```

But that is not what you want yet, not in this form, so you have to convert it using the array's [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```js
<array>.map(([title, quantity]) => ({title, quantity}))
```

To keep it concise it uses the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)